# A problem with going to Sculpting mode

Tags: sculpting

I'm trying to go to sculpting mode, but then my object becomes flat and solid-colored. How do I change it? It works okay when I try to access sculpting through  the list in the top-left corner, while it stays in Layout mode. Thanks in advance

PS When I change it to Flat, the object becomes all white.

[image]

Comment: [How to upload an image to a post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Answer (score 0):

If someone has a similar problem. Rolling back the drivers of my graphic card has helped.